# Forcing an mvc route for a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have the following two routes defined within my applications.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
             "ApplicationRoutes",
             "{language}-{country}/{userid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { language="en" , country="gb",  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default",
             "{language}-{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { language = "en", country = "gb",  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The first route will be catching urls like

- en-gb/11111/Targets/List
- en-gb/11111/Targets/Edit/2

The second route is the default route which will be used for things like this

- en-gn/Account/Logon
- etc

The question I have is I have certain controllers which I want to force to only be invoked if they have come via the applicationRoutes route.

for example I want to make sure the targets controller is invoked with the userid within the routedata.

I know I can check within each controller action if the userid key exists with a value within the routedata. But this doesn't seem that elegant to me.

I could also be more specific about the routes and do something like this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             "ApplicationRoutes",
             "{language}-{country}/{userid}/Targets/{action}/{id}",
            new { language="en" , country="gb", controller="targets", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But this wouldn't stop the request directly to en-gb/Targets/List/ without supplying the userid value.

what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a restriction for userid parameter.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             "ApplicationRoutes",
             "{language}-{country}/{userid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new { language="en" , country="gb",  id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              new { userid =@"\d+" });
```

This will make sure userid is a valid integer, otherwise next route will be used for handling the request.

Comment: Great. That would work perfect if there were one controller which need this, but lets say that I have numerous controllers which would need a userid. I could implement a specific route for each controller as you have indicated, but is there a more elegant solution to creating a route for each controller?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the controller restriction there. You can leave the controller variable as it is.

Comment: even with the restriction, surely this is not going to stop me going to /en-gb/Targets/List without the userid within the route because the default route would handle this. I would want to make sure that every action invoked on the targets controller contained the userid in the routedata.

Comment: Well if you are careful when you are generating URLs this won't be an issue. Otherwise you can't stop people messing with it, there will always be invalid URLs. There can be some some complicated rules that may do want you want, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: would an action method selector be the most appropriate option? http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/using-custom-action-method-selector.html. could this be applied to those controller actions which need the userid and the method selector check that it exists in the route data and if not returns is not valid for request?